Can I make Jackson fasterxml prefer @JsonProperty over @JsonAlias if both are present?
My JSON payload used to be:
{ "a": "some-value" }

And I mapped it to:
class Item {

  @JsonProperty("a")
  public String value;

}

Now I want to deprecate property a and introduce a new property b in its place. For a grace period, both shall be accepted.
@JsonAlias seems to be the best way to achieve this:
class Item {

  @JsonProperty("b")
  @JsonAlias("a")
  public String value;

}

It works perfect when either a or b are present, and when both are present and b comes after a:
{ "b": "some-value" }

{ "a": "some-value" }

{ "a": "this-is-ignored", "b": "uses-this-value" }

However, the properties are processed in order and Jackson will choose whichever comes last, so if the deprecated property is at the end, it wins:
{ "b": "it-should-use-this-value", "a": "but-uses-this-one-instead" }

Is there a way I can configure Jackson to always prefer the main mapping and ignore the aliases if multiple are present?

According to this issue comment this behaviour is expected.

No. Best think you can do is custom deserializer for whole class.
